# How to Connect RJ45 Cabled Internet (WiMax) to a Wireless ADSL2+ Modem Router?

Tags: wireless-router

I was using [TP LINK Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TD-W8961ND) which was one side connected to landline phone and another side had 4 ethernet port and also act as wifi router. Now I brought BSNL WiMax where the internet comes directly in RJ45 cable. I don't like to buy a separate wifi router. Is it possible connect this RJ45 cable to one port out of 4 port of that existing ADSL2+ Modem Router to get wifi connection and also to connect desktop system with balance 3 port? 
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

A few ADSL modem/routers have the capability of separating the modem section from the router section, and offer a WAN port (usually by re-purposing LAN port #1).  But the vast majority of ADSL modem/routers hard-wire the WAN-side of the router to the downstream-side of the ADSL modem.  The TP-Link unit that you have seems to be of the latter hard-wired type, and therefore unusable in your new setup as a router.

If you disable the router features in the TP-Link (e.g. DHCP server, NAT, firewall etc.), then the LAN ports could be used as a switch and the wireless section used as an access point.  Such a setup requires that the BSNL WiMax unit be the router for your network, and provide DHCP and NAT services.  As you planned, one of the TP-Link's LAN ports would be connected to the BSNL's ports.

There are three interfaces that you have to setup in the TP-Link: Internet, LAN and Wireless.

- Try to setup the "Internet" (WAN and ADSL side) interface to benign values, e.g. try setting the "Virtual Circuit - status" to "disabled".
- You should setup the TP-Link's LAN interface with a static IP address that is within your subnet but outside the assignable DHCP range (issued by the BSNL WiMax).  For instance my modem/router has IP address 192.168.1.1 for its LAN side, and its DHCP server hands out IP addresses in the range 192.168.1.100 through 192.168.1.199.  A second wireless router (used in the same manner that you want to use your TP-Link) has (static) IP address 192.168.1.2 for its LAN side, and all of its "router" features are disabled.
- The Wireless interface should be an ordinary WPA configuration.